# How to programmatically install tts language data for a specific language?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have my android system set in english and, as obvious, the text to speech default language is english also. I'm developing an app using the text to speech feature but need to speech japanese language. Here is the problem. The tts call getAvailableLanguages() return all the possible languages managed by the tts engine BUT this doesn't mean it are immediately available. For use a specific language (in my case japanese) the language data have to be manually downloaded and installed into the system.
Now my question is, how is possible to make this action programmatically? Reading the documentation it report the following example:

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

But is not clear regarding HOW to tell I need to install the japanese language data ONLY. I googled a lot but didn't find a solution. I'm sure it can be done cause I found and app that make it automatically (after I selected the tts feature the system started to download and install the language data automatically).

Someone know how to reach such result?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  This opens up an Activity that lets the user choose 1 or more language to download.  There is no way to download it directly without user interaction.

Comment: This app is able to do that. Just select the tts option and it automatically install the japanese language.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.takoboto

Comment: @Suppaman Not possible.  You can't even promise that a particular TTS engine is installed (users and OEMs can install their own).  They all get their TTS data from different places and in different formats.  There is no way to know which one the user is using and install it.  If they do have something, it at most works for a subset of devices